Dash Application - user level authentication
I have created a Dash Application using python Dash module with plotly as my graphing library. Now I want to add user level authentication to my Dash application, i.e. based on the user type i want to expose graphs specific to that user. How can I achieve that?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Since you are using Python for this, you can use flask-login to do the authentication. Simply you can create a login API with your customizations.
